# How to set a td's width to 0

Tags: html, css, html-table

How can I set the width of an td to 0? I have a td without any content in it but it has always a width of 2px.

My first suspicion was the border-spacing property but setting it to 0 doesn't help neither.

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[See Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/PZkSa/1/)

Comment: Can't you do a `display:none`?

Comment: what is reason for doing this?

Comment: border, padding, margin and border-spacing, these contribute to TDs' width. Check if you have any of them.

Comment: @AlanPiralla No margin on `td`

Answer (score 7):

Set `td`s padding to 0 adding `padding: 0;` to your `td` css rule.

Comment: also make sure border-collapse is set to collapse.

Comment: Is it also possible to reduce a TDs width to 0 if it has content in it?

http://jsfiddle.net/PZkSa/12/

Comment: @juleee - set font-size=0;

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to remove the padding. ( td { padding: 0; })

Modern web browsers make it quite easy to track down questions like this. For example, using the Chrome Developer tools you can highlight the element and take a look at the Metrics tab and find out what is causing your width.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your css should be:

```
td{
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0;
}
```

**Update Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/PZkSa/5/

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are mostly correct, but something you may also need to do is set any corresponding table heading cells (`<th/>`) in the same way:

```css
table {

  border-collapse: collapse

}

td, th {

  padding: 0;

}
```