# webkit empty td is 1px

Tags: css, layout, webkit, html-email

I'm designing an html email template for my company. I am positioning text over background images using an old html table hack that looks something like this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td rowspan="2">Background image goes here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Text will be displayed over top of the background image</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

this works fine in web browsers like firefox but in chrome and safari I noticed the empty `<td>` from the first row has a width of 1px and it is breaks the design.

I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qQH3x/) to demonstrate the effect in my email template design. The line with the links to Promotions, Gift Cards, and Contact is where the effect is most noticeable. You can see the white edges of that row look offset by 1px. Looks fine in Firefox you have to use Chrome or Safari to see the issue.

This technique to use background images in email is the most compatible way I've found. Are there any better ways? Is there any way to get webkit browsers to render the `<td>` as zero width?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025138/how-to-set-a-tds-width-to-0

Seen no long ago :)

Comment: @GCyrillus I already have cellpadding=0 on my table and I tried adding td { padding:0; } but it had no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know to make background images work for emails in all (relevant) browsers and clients is NOT to use background images, and especially no fancy hacks, no matter how interesting the technique may be.

You should be able to make the layout in your fiddle work, by slicing up your banner image and adding a few more cells. Similar to the way you made the rounded corners work...

Answer (score 0):

Your extra 1px shows once in a while.

Your stacking tables on top of each other, and margin:auto can move from a pixel.

Set borders to your tables to see where they stand, you may manage margin inside tables instead empty sized td .
http://jsfiddle.net/F9ZjT/1/

```
/* removed left td and put 20px margin on row links for example. + borders to show tables area */
```